# Why is access time greater than modify and change time in this case

Tags: linux, bash

I have

```
$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 abc root 7 2011-09-18 19:41 a
-rw-r--r-- 1 abc root 7 2011-09-18 19:41 b



I do
$ strace -tt cat * >d


I get
$ stat d
  File: `d'
  Size: 14          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 803h/2051d  Inode: 2093326     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/   abc)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2011-09-18 23:09:26.130876919 -0700
Modify: 2011-09-18 23:09:26.140844318 -0700
Change: 2011-09-18 23:09:26.140844318 -0700
```

Why is atime greater than mtime and ctime?

But when I do this:

```
  $ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 abc root 7 2011-09-18 19:41 a
-rw-r--r-- 1 abc root 7 2011-09-18 19:41 b

$ cat * >d

I get
$ stat d
  File: `d'
  Size: 14          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 803h/2051d  Inode: 2093326     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/   abc)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2011-09-18 23:16:58.300875204 -0700
Modify: 2011-09-18 23:16:58.300875204 -0700
Change: 2011-09-18 23:16:58.300875204 -0700
```

Here all times are same. Why the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atime is lower, not greater, which makes sense since you are writing to the file, and atime is only updated on reading it (and in your case creating it).

Comment: But why are all the times same in the second case when I don't use strace with cat? Why is it that strace makes a difference?

Comment: My guess is that strace causes the command to take much longer, in addition it does not allow the shell to simply copy the files contents, but require a pipe from a program (strace).